# For which primes $p$ can one always find $q$ such that $X^2+(pq-1)Y^2 \equiv 0\!\pmod{p^2}$ has no solution?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, congruences, quadratic-forms

For which primes $p$ can one always find an integer $q$ such that the congruence
$$X^2+(pq-1)Y^2 \equiv 0\!\pmod{p^2}$$
has no solution for co-prime integers $x,y$?

Comment: $X=Y$  is always a solution ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Sorry! Forgot the $x,y$ coprime restriction.

Comment: $y=x+p$? Also, $x=y=1$ makes $x,y$ coprime.

Comment: @Wojowu: Rats… Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $x^2+(pq-1)y^2\equiv 0 \mod p\iff x^2\equiv y^2\mod p$? The assertion in question is independent of $q$.

Comment: @RedundantAunt: Yes. My brain was clearly off.

Comment: Thanks, all, for pointing out the trivial nature of the original question. It's now a supercongruence (modulo $p^2$), which may not be as trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p=q$, we always have a solution $X=Y=1$.

Consider $p\neq q$. We will look at solutions with $X=Y+p$. We then have
$$X^2+(pq-1)Y^2=Y^2+2Yp+p^2+pqY^2-Y^2\equiv pY(2+qY)\pmod{p^2}.$$
Since $p\neq q$, we can solve $2+qY\pmod p$, and then $Y\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ unless $p=2$. Such $Y$ and $X=Y+p$ will solve your congruence. So for $p\neq 2$ there is no $q$ you seek for.

For $p=2$, we can take $q=3$, since then $X^2+(pq-1)Y^2\equiv X^2+Y^2\pmod 4$, and it's easy to see this is $0\pmod 4$ iff both $X,Y$ are even.